# Unable to setup Hadoop in pseudo mode

Tags: configuration, hadoop

I have set up Hadoop on my computer in pseudo-distributed mode.
I followed the directions in Appendix A of 'Hadoop - A Definitive Guide' book to setup Hadoop in a pseudo-distributed mode.

However, from the output of following program, it is safe to infer that my Hadoop is running into standalone mode (i.e. local mode).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    System.out.println(conf);
    System.out.println(conf.get("fs.default.name"));
}
```

Output:

```
Configuration: core-default.xml, core-site.xml
file:///
```

The output is `file:///` instead of `hdfs://localhost`. However the properties in `core-site.xml` are properly set:

```
<configuration>
        <property>
                <name>fs.default.name</name>
                <value>hdfs://localhost/</value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

Also when I submit a test job from Eclipse, it doesn't show up in jobTracker browser UI, I read somewhere that it is due to the fact that Hadoop is running in local mode.

Please let me know what's wrong in my configuration and how I can enable pseudo-distributed mode. Why am I not able to override `fs.default.name` property in default XML file with that I specified in `core-site.xml` file?

Comment: add a port to fs.default.name, e.G. hdfs://localhost:9000/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you launching the program? If you're not using the bin/hadoop script then the configuration files in conf/*.xml will not be on the classpath, and hence any values in them will be ignored.

You should also use the ToolRunner launcher:

```
public class MyJobDriver extends Configured implements Tool {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    ToolRunner.run(new MyJobDriver(), args);
  }

  public int run(String args[]) {
    Job job = new Job(getConf());
    Configuration conf = job.getConfiguration();

    System.out.println(conf);
    System.out.println(conf.get("fs.default.name"));

    return 0;
  }
}
```

Some other points to note from this code:

- Remember to create your Job with the Configuration provided by getConf() - this allows you to use the Generic Options Parser to parse out some common command line switches (-files, -jt, -fs, =Dkey=value etc)
- If you need the Configuration to set some custom parameters - get the job copy using job.getConfiguration() - as Job makes a deep copy when you construct it, and any changes to the original will not be applied when you job runs

Then ensure you job is run using the bin/hadoop script:

```
#> bin/hadoop MyApp.jar a.b.c.MyAppDriver
```

If you're lauching from Eclipse, ensure the $HADOOP_HOME/conf folder is on the classpath and than will ensure the xml conf files are on the classpath when the Configuration object is created by the ToolRunner.

Comment: Thanks. Even before I implement what you suggested, why do you say that all the properties in $HADOOP_INSTALL/conf/*xml files will be ingored? After all, from the output, it is quite clear that core-site.xml is being picked up, whether in classpath or not. Am I missing something here about classpath?

Comment: If you don't launch your code via the bin/hadoop script then the conf folder will not be added to the classpath, hence the properties will be ignored. The output of System.out.println(conf) shows the files core-default and core-site.xml, but they are just place holders for files that are expected to be on the classpath, and will be loaded if they are. You've already proved that they are not being loaded as fs.default.name is not the value you have configured in core-site.xml